# Google Maps Multiple Instances

Tags: google-maps

I am new on google maps devlopment. I am using google map javasccript api v3.

using the below url 
url : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
I was able to generate the key that is required to generate/display map. I tried a sample example for this.

What I would actually like to know is: can we add **multiple instances of google maps** on a page at the same time?*

Also, I am bit confused like there is a limit for number of times a map can be loaded in a day (some 25,000) and if exceeds that there would be charge for the next request for that particular map?

Comment: You are asking two questions here, please separate out the limit of times question into a new one.

Answer (score 2):

1) In the Google Dev Console, it states that the Android Google Maps v2 call does not have a limit whereas regular Google Maps v2 has one set at (25,000). I would link to the console, but you have to be logged in.

2) No, I do not think that you can have multiple instances of maps running on one activity at a time.

Hope this helps.